# Правильное оформление заголовка/колонтитула [Название произведения. Глава, часть. Название части]

Tags: сокращения, заголовок

Как правильно оформить заголовок или колонтитул:

> Мемуары на R&D,  ч. 4. Клондайк

Второй вариант:

> Мемуары на R&D. Глава 2, ч. 4. Клондайк

- Мемуары на R&D - это название серии постов (как название произведения)
- ч. 4 - это сокращение от часть 4, нужна ли точка после 4? Или там запятая? Хотя логичнее двоеточие :)
- Клондайк - это название части. Нужно ли брать в кавычки? Или можно и так?
- После "клондайк" точку не ставлю же?
- Как правильно сократить главу? Г. 2, ч. 4?
- Ещё какие советы/пожелания? Может "мемуары на R&D" нужно в кавычки тоже брать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Получается, у главы 2 несколько частей?

Comment: Я пока думаю, делить ли на главы или нет... не хочется усложнять, но частей получается много... поэтому в одной главе будет неизбежно несколько частей. Так же не нравится, что, например, часть четвёртая может быть и в первой главе и во второй, мне уже нельзя будет сказать кому-нибудь: почитай 4-ю часть мемуаров. Так что скорее всего главы делать не буду. Но интересно знать как правильно пишется (с главами) на будущее.

Comment: Почему спросил... Просто обычно части делятся на главы. Том 2, часть 1, глава 8.

Comment: Да, со ступенями рубрикации (делением на части) прежде всего надо определиться. Обычное деление такое: название произведения – часть – раздел – глава – параграф. Часть воспринимается как старшая рубрика, Надо как-то иначе назвать параграф (деление главы). Может быть, пост, статья? Или нужно что-нибудь креативное) Можно оставить параграф как вариант, но это больше подходит для научной или учебной литературы.

Comment: Спс, я же двоечник... книжки не читаю, поэтому даже не знал, что глава ниже части стоит)

Answer (score 1):

В качестве **варианта:**

На **четной** полосе: Мемуары на R&D. Глава 2

На **нечетной** полосе: Пост 4. Клондайк

**Пояснение**

Колонтитул на нечетной полосе содержит **низшую** ступень рубрикации, на четной полосе — **высшую**.

Если, например, в книге четыре части, тридцать шесть глав и около трехсот параграфов, и последние являются **рабочими заголовками**, то на четную полосу следует поместить названия глав. В этом случае текст колонтитула будет строиться, например, следующим образом:

```
 Пример 1
 Четная полоса: Глава I. Общие вопросы проектирования
 Нечетная полоса: § 2. Расположение и габариты котлов
```

**[Построение колонтитула](https://www31.ru/book/imposition/378-postroenie-kolontitula.html)**